# C++ Getting a runtime error in some compilers

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, runtime-error

I made a solution for uva problem 5355 Link: 
 https://icpcarchive.ecs.baylor.edu/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&category=&problem=3356&mosmsg=Submission+received+with+ID+1242500?

I made the solution and it is running fine on my pc , i used overall dev c++ IDE, but when I submitted the program on the uva site, they gave me a message runtime error . Heres what the mailed me

"Your submission with number 1242500 for the problem 5355 - Baudot Data Communication Code has failed with verdict Runtime error.

This means that the execution of your program didn't finish properly. Remember to always terminate your code with the exit code 0."

I checked my program it was running fine on my pc, so for checking I went to http://www.compileonline.com/ and tried to compile it online .

it gave me a runtime error of terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::substr

Please can you check what is wrong with my program, I am pasting the source code .

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cstring>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std ;

int main(){
  char check ;
  int i = 0 ;
  struct forbinary{
    char ds;
    char us;
    char bin[20];

  }b[35] ;


  char type = 'd' ;

  strcpy(b[0].bin,"00000");
  strcpy(b[1].bin,"00001");
  strcpy(b[2].bin,"00010");
  strcpy(b[3].bin,"00011");
  strcpy(b[4].bin,"00100");
  strcpy(b[5].bin,"00101");
  strcpy(b[6].bin,"00110");
  strcpy(b[7].bin,"00111");
  strcpy(b[8].bin,"01000");
  strcpy(b[9].bin,"01001");
  strcpy(b[10].bin,"01010");
  strcpy(b[11].bin,"01011");
  strcpy(b[12].bin,"01100");
  strcpy(b[13].bin,"01101");
  strcpy(b[14].bin,"01110");
  strcpy(b[15].bin,"01111");
  strcpy(b[16].bin,"10000");
  strcpy(b[17].bin,"10001");
  strcpy(b[18].bin,"10010");
  strcpy(b[19].bin,"10011");
  strcpy(b[20].bin,"10100");
  strcpy(b[21].bin,"10101");
  strcpy(b[22].bin,"10110");
  strcpy(b[23].bin,"10111");
  strcpy(b[24].bin,"11000");
  strcpy(b[25].bin,"11001");
  strcpy(b[26].bin,"11010");
  strcpy(b[27].bin,"11011");
  strcpy(b[28].bin,"11100");
  strcpy(b[29].bin,"11101");
  strcpy(b[30].bin,"11110");
  strcpy(b[31].bin,"11111");    


  FILE *fp ;
  fp = fopen("inp.txt","r");
  char str[401] ;
  string temp , temp2;


  fgets(str,80,fp);
  int j = strlen(str) ;

  for(i=0;i<j-1;i++){
    b[i].ds = str[i] ; 
  }


  fgets(str,80,fp);

  for(i=0;i<j-1;i++){
    b[i].us = str[i] ;
  }

  int x = 0 , y = 0,z=0, size , s;
  while(fgets(str,400,fp)!=NULL){
    type = 'd' ;
    temp = str ;
    size = temp.size();
    s = size ;
    x = 0 ;
    y = 5 ;

    while(size){

      temp2 = temp.substr(x,y) ;


      if(temp2=="11011")
        type = 'd' ;
      else if(temp2=="11111") 
        type = 'u' ;

      for(i=0;i<j-1;i++){

        if(temp2==b[i].bin){
          if(type=='d')
            cout << b[i].ds;
          else if(type=='u')
            cout << b[i].us;     
        }
      }

      if(s==x+6){
        break ;
      }

      x += y ;
      size-=5;
    }

    temp="";
    strcpy(str,"");
    cout << endl ;
  }
  fclose(fp) ;
  return 0 ;
}
```

the inp.txt file contains these four lines

```
<T*O HNM=LRGIPCVEZDBSYFXAWJ UQK 
>5@9 %,.+)4&80:;3"$?#6!/-2' 71( 
100100110011000010011111101110000111110111101
001100001101111001001111100001001100010001100110111100000111
```

I am not able to find out the problem, please help

Comment: You have undefined behaviour: `fflush(stdin);` Who knows what will haapen.

Comment: I used it after I started getting error and removing it is'nt helping

Comment: on `fopen` are you sure the file exists? `fopen` fails if you use `r` and the file does not exist. If you're running it on another computer, it might not be there.

Comment: That's a problem , I didn't find any info on the uva site about what file to use . But on the online compiler site i mentioned above , theres a option for including file. the program runs half way and as soon as it encounters a \n after the 3rd line , it gives that error

Comment: Why are you using C-style stream functions instead of C++ functions?

Comment: Cause I don't know them yet.

Comment: can you just check it if its compiling and running on your computer

Answer (score 1):

A few of things to fix:

```
FILE * InputFile = fopen("input.txt", "r") // fails if the file doesn't exist
```

You should check to see if it's opening or not:

```
if (!InputFile){
    cerr << "Couldn't open input file" << endl; 
    // alternatively: perror ("Couldn't open input file");
    return 0;
}
```

Since your not checking this in your code, it can very easily cause a cascade of runtime errors in the rest of your code (like all the calls to `fgets`). It can make it look like one of the other functions is causing an error, when really it is this one.

---

This is a problem:

```
for(i=0;i<j-1;i++){
    b[i].ds = str[i] ; 
}
```

It's a problem because `b[]` only goes up to `35` but your code suggest the string might be 80 chars long - this might also cause a segmentation fault. Maybe you should check if `j - 1` is greater than zero before you enter the loop:

```
if ((j -1) < 0){
    cout << "Oops!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

In your second `fgets`, you do not calculate the string length before you enter the loop. In addition to adding `strlen` to that, you should check again to make sure that `(j - 1) > 0`.

---

Before calling this:

```
 temp2 = temp.substr(x,y) ;
```

Check to mark sure `temp` contains a string greater than `y`, or else you could get a segmentation fault. This is because you can a sub-string that is bigger than the source string. Use this:

```
if (temp2.size() < y){
    cout << "Oops, string was too small" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `temp2` is a `std::string`.

Comment: I think the J could be a problem, checking it

Comment: Why would that loop cause segmentation faults? The loop wont run if `j ==0` because 0 isn't less than -1.

Comment: Nope J is not a problem , according to problem j is the strlen and it wiil be maximum 33 including the newline char . so j - 1 = 32 and 0 - 31 is 32 elements. And J wont be zero.

Comment: can you just check it if its compiling and running on your computer

Comment: Yes, it compiles fine on my computer. I'm continuously updating my answer, so just keep checking for things you may have not tried.

Comment: @user1520427 it wouldn't. For some reason I had it in my mind that `I` was an unsigned interger (which would have caused that problem).

Comment: 80 wont be a problem the maximum number of chars on line 1 and line 2 are going to be 32

Comment: Did you check my last suggestion? Checking the size of `temp` before getting the `substr`?

Comment: i DIDNT UNDERSTAD WHAT YOU MEAN BY  GREATER THEN Y

Comment: I AM NOW TRYING TO TAKE INPUT FROM THE KEYBOARD